# How do I pull the contents of a thread matching search criteria into a Google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I currently have a Google Apps Script running a spreadsheet that pulls the correct Email I am querying for. However, I can only get the original email body contents, when I am actually trying to pull a thread reply in the actual email conversation.

Does anyone know if this is possible or how to go about doing so?

My current script only pulls the initial email from the search query, but this is not the intention.

```
function myFunction() {
  // Use sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  // Gmail query
  var query = "subject:Attendance Shed";
  // Search in Gmail, bind to array
  var threads = GmailApp.search(query);
  // Loop through query results
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
  {
    // Get messages in thread, add to array
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

    // Used to find max index in array
    var max = messages[0];
    var maxIndex = 0;

    // Loop through array to find maxIndexD = most recent mail
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
      if (messages[j] > max) {
        maxIndex = j;
        max = messages[j];
      }
    } 
    // Find data
    var mId = messages[maxIndex].getId() // ID used to create mail link
    var from = messages[maxIndex].getFrom();
    var cc = messages[maxIndex].getCc();
    var time = threads[i].getLastMessageDate()
    var sub = messages[maxIndex].getSubject();
    // Write data to sheet
    ss.appendRow([from, cc, time, sub, 'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/'+mId])
  }
}
```

I expect it to be able to retrieve a specific thread using the search query given and output it to a Spreadsheet. Currently it only pulls the initial email.

Comment: When you're checking `if (messages[j] > max)` you're comparing two message objects, it is not going to check their order. If you are trying to iterate through the thread you can do it by removing the `maxIndex` loop, you can go through all messages in that loop and append them from there. right now your `appendRow` is only being called once per thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code after the `var messages = threads[i].getMessages();` line:

```
…

for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
    // Find data
    var mId = messages[j].getId() // ID used to create mail link
    var from = messages[j].getFrom();
    var cc = messages[j].getCc();
    var time = threads[i].getLastMessageDate()
    var sub = messages[j].getSubject();
    // Write data to sheet
    ss.appendRow([from, cc, time, sub, 'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/' + mId])
}
ss.appendRow();
```

This will get each message’s information, and then append an empty row to separate between each thread.