# Extract gmail data (day of last contact) to google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, gmail, gmail-addons

I m trying to collect on a google spreadsheet the dates of the latest activity related to one specific email adresse.

So ideally, I'd like to input a list of email adresses and get on the next column the date of the latest interaction (incoming or outcoming email)

I've been looking for an add-on, but no luck for now.

Anyone can help ?

Many thanks,

Jeremy

Comment: i found this other reply more helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56781080/how-do-i-pull-the-contents-of-a-thread-matching-search-criteria-into-a-google-sh

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

This can easily be achieved using Apps Script. In the Spreadsheet with your email addresses go to **Tools->Script Editor** and use the code below by running the script (**Run->Run function -> myFunction**).

This is the piece of code that performs what you were trying to achieve with comments explaining how it works:

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Get the value in the cell A1 (which will have the email to check the latest interaction)
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('A1').getValue();
  
  // Search the date of the last message of the search from the email in cell A1 and log it
  var latestEmail = GmailApp.search('from:"'+ss+'"')[0].getLastMessageDate();
  Logger.log(latestEmail);
  
  // Print the date on the cell to the right
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('B1').setValue(latestEmail);
}
```

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)

Comment: Hey Matéo, hope everything is going well for you - thanks a lot for your reply : )